# Build telegram for Android from source code - change package name

Tags: android-studio, telegram

I downloaded the telegram source code for android from here: "https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram"

I change the package name in this file: "gradle.properties"
when building, I get the following errors

Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: ERROR: Failed to verify AGConnect-Config '/client/package_name', expected: 'org.MY_PACKAGE_NAME', but was: 'org.telegram.messenger'

Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: No matching client found for package name 'org.MY_PACKAGE_NAME'

Thanks